# ggplotly issue with encoding

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am using the ggplotly function to turn a static ggplot2 bar graph into an interactive one.

However, my output returns a graph with encoding issues - shown below.

[image]

My ggplot2 graph is fine though.

Edit: Dataframe below

head(test2)

```
IRO_NAME_AND_SURNAME           correct   incorrect   percent
## 1        НАУМ ДИМИТРОВСКИ       0         2 100.00000
## 2     АЛЕКСАНДАР МИРЧЕСКИ    1708       460  21.21771
## 3 НАДИЦА ИЛОСКА НИКОЛОСКА    1736       440  20.22059
## 4         ЕЛЕНА ТОДОРОСКА    2009       472  19.02459
## 5         ГОЦЕ ПУПАЛЕВСКИ     849       186  17.97101
## 6    АНА МИЛЕСКА ЛАТКОСКА    2155       447  17.17909
```

Creation of ggplot2 object.

```
 b <- ggplot(test2, aes(as.factor(IRO_NAME_AND_SURNAME), percent)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat="identity", fill = "deepskyblue4") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank()) +
  ggtitle(expression(atop(bold("test test test"), atop(italic("NBI: 2011 - 2016"), "")))) +   
  xlab("") + ylab("") +
  geom_text(aes(label=percent), color='white') 

ggplotly(b)
```

Comment: Please put the sample of the  values in your question, so that a solution can be worked

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: I have read the instructions multiple times, thank you. I am not sure how in this particular case the dataframe or the function call would be helpful, as there is only one function (ggplotly) that calls for an object, which otherwise plots fine.

Comment: Anyhow, I updated the question. Anyone with a hint?

Comment: @Prometheus Not sure what is happening there, but please backup your locale settings as below: `oldloc <- Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")`  then run `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "ru_RU") ` see if this changes things in your plot. In case you want to return to previous setting just run, `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", oldloc)`

Comment: The sys local is: Sys.getlocale("LC_CTYPE")
[1] "Macedonian (FYROM)_Macedonia (FYROM).1251" I don't think Russian settings are gonna work :S

Comment: @Prometheus I am getting a graph with the names as you have given I am not getting any gibberish values  . Not sure why you are getting it though